# Is the quantum system around the Scrödinger's cat limited without justification?

Tags: schroedingers-cat

In Schrödinger's cat experiment, the quantum mechanical system is expanded from the atom to a nearby cat,
but there is no justification for stoppning the expansion there. It is natural also to include the observer/observing system in the same expansion.

Is that not a problem?

Comment: That is no problem, it is called Everett interpretation (MWI).

Comment: Schrodinger's Cat was a not very good (IMO) attempt to illustrate some concepts in quantum theory.  Schrodinger was way better at quantum theory than I ever will be, but maybe not so good at explaining it to ordinary people.